# Dealing with invalid foreign keys during EF seeding import

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, constraints, seeding

In copying data from an old schema to a new schema I have found cases where foreign keys are missing in the old data. For example the `Vehicle` table contains a field `VehicleTypeId` which is a link to the primary key `Id` in the table `VehicleType`. Some of the vehicle records I am importing have a `VehicleTypeId` that is not present in the `VehicleType` table.

In the new schema foreign key constraints are in place so the `VehicleTypeId` must be present in the `VehicleType` table in order for the record to fulfill the constraint. I don't want to lose the record but I am unsure what `VehicleTypeId` to give it.

I thought of assigning `VehicleTypeId = -1` but as the `VehcileType` table has an Identity based primary key that does not include `-1`. I am using Entity Framework and seeding that data via code. Is there a way after seeding the `VehicleType` table to add a final row that would reference an "unknown vehicle type"?

I figure other must have run into this situation. What have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what we do, assuming you can't make VehicleTypeId nullable. SSIS is a great tool for this kind of thing, but you could hammer it into EF. So you need to seed the VehicleType table, store a reference to the empty id, then import the vehicles:

```
if (!db.VehicleTypes.Any(v => v.Description == "Unknown")
{
    var emptyVehicleType = new VehicleType { Description = "Unknown" };
    db.VehicleTypes.Add(emptyVehicleType);
    db.SaveChanges();  // emptyVehicleType.VehicleTypeId will now be filled in
}
```

then in the vehicle inserting:

```
    var newVehicle = new Vehicle { VehicleTypeId = oldVehTypeId == 0 ? emptyVehicleType.VehicleTypeId: oldVehicleTypeId,
                                   otherNewField = otherOldField,
                                   etc.
                                 }
```

Comment: I see what your saying. I did not know that the `Add` method would return the primary key.

Comment: Actually, I usually just use the added entity now that I look at my code. Will correct.